# Error to convert xlsx to xls

Tags: java, excel

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFComment cannot be cast to 
  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFComment
```

When I try to compile the following code.

I used the library `poi 3.11` and `dom4j-1.6.1` and `xmlbeans 2.3.0`

I compile this code on mac with Eclipse Luna.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class FormulasExcel {

    private String outFn;
    private File inpFn;

    public FormulasExcel(File inpFn){
        this.outFn = inpFn + ".xls";
        this.inpFn = inpFn;
    }

    public void xlsx2xls_progress() throws InvalidFormatException,IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(inpFn);
        try {
            XSSFWorkbook wbIn = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
            File outF = new File(outFn);
            if (outF.exists()) {
                outF.delete();
            }

            Workbook wbOut = new HSSFWorkbook();
            int sheetCnt = wbIn.getNumberOfSheets();
            for (int i = 0; i < sheetCnt; i++) {
                Sheet sIn = wbIn.getSheetAt(0);
                Sheet sOut = wbOut.createSheet(sIn.getSheetName());
                Iterator<Row> rowIt = sIn.rowIterator();
                while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
                    Row rowIn = rowIt.next();
                    Row rowOut = sOut.createRow(rowIn.getRowNum());

                    Iterator<Cell> cellIt = rowIn.cellIterator();
                    while (cellIt.hasNext()) {
                        Cell cellIn = cellIt.next();
                        Cell cellOut = rowOut.createCell(cellIn.getColumnIndex(), cellIn.getCellType());

                        switch (cellIn.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK: break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getBooleanCellValue());
                            break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                            cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getErrorCellValue());
                            break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                            cellOut.setCellFormula(cellIn.getCellFormula());
                            break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getStringCellValue());
                            break;
                        }

                        {
                            CellStyle styleIn = cellIn.getCellStyle();
                            CellStyle styleOut = cellOut.getCellStyle();
                            styleOut.setDataFormat(styleIn.getDataFormat());
                        }cellOut.setCellComment(cellIn.getCellComment());

                        }
                }
            }
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outF));
            try {
                wbOut.write(out);
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{

        FormulasExcel doit = new FormulasExcel(new File("/Users/Downloads/Layout.xlsx"));
        doit.xlsx2xls_progress();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you include the stacktrace with which line causes the error? Basically this error tells you that you are trying to cast a class to another in an non allowed way. But the reasons for this can be many.

Comment: Also, have you tried this with different files as input? It might depend of unexpected input data from the file.

Comment: What line is generating the exception?

Comment: Stacktrace:          Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFComment cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFComment
 at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.setCellComment(HSSFCell.java:1018)
 at FormulasExcel.xlsx2xls_progress(FormulasExcel.java:82)
 at FormulasExcel.main(FormulasExcel.java:101)

Comment: And your line 82 is???

Comment: sorry is my first time that I post a question, but it is the line:     cellOut.setCellComment(cellIn.getCellComment());

Comment: It sounds like you've mixed up two separate libraries -- org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel and org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel -- and they are not compatible with each other.